# ConfigServerHealthIndicator is not checking the right profile

Tags: spring-cloud

We are investigating why our spring config server is always returning is health status "DOWN", even if it's actually working.

After debugging in the spring framework, we found the ConfigServerHealthIndicator class, is always reading the "default" profile.

This is the issue for us as the default profile is not working in our production environment and we would expect the config server to read the appropriate repository.

From what we can see on the code, setRepositories is not call at all.

Is there any configuration we missed to make the ConfigServerHealthIndicator read the appropriate repository?
Overriding the bean maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. *I missed the annotation '@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config.server.health")' which means this class is a mapper of the config.*

If you hit the same issue than me, have a look at [Heath Indicator](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#_health_indicator) in official docs

You need to setup a repository config like:

```yml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        health:
          repositories:
            myservice:
              label: mylabel
            myservice-dev:
              name: myservice
              profiles: development
```

Or you can disbale this check.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.health.enabled=false
```